# jQuery: how to get original value of this in methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, this

I'm trying to have some object oriented design using JS and jQuery.
I have the following construstor:

```
function A () {
  this.url = "some url";

   $("rrr").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, add){
       $.getJSON(this.url, req, function(data) {} ...
}
```

As you guessed, I can't use **this.url**, since jQuery redefienes **this**. I can't use just url without this, since it is not declared.
What I came up is to have something like this:

```
function A () {
  this.url = "some url";
  var url = this.url;

   $("rrr").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, add){
       $.getJSON(url, req, function(data) {} ...
}
```

But this is just plain ugly, and works only for properties.

Is there a better way to fetch value of **this** from original scope in jquery methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the 'this' reference being a reference to the object that triggered the event. Keeping a reference to 'this' in your class when it is instanciated is not ideal but will get around this problem (you could call it anything you want but usually 'self' or '_this' is what I call it).

```
function A () {
  var _this = this;
  _this.url = "some url";


   $("rrr").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, add){
       $.getJSON(_this.url, req, function(data) {} ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I hoped for something prettier, but still, this also works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to set `this` in the context of the function, like this:

```
function A () {
  this.url = "some url";
  $("rrr").autocomplete({
     source: $.proxy(function(req, add){
               $.getJSON(this.url, req, function(data) {});
             }, this)
  });
}
```

Or you can do it long hand by returning a function with the context set, but since you didn't like your current work-around, I'm guessing [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) is much more appealing in your case, [and not really much overhead at all here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L749).